# unrecognized command line option when running make -j4 command to download openCV on raspberry 3 B+

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to install OpenCV on raspberryPi 3 B+.

I'm following [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-raspberry-pi-for-computer-vision-installing-opencv-e0f973d38819) guide:

Im running this line which is towards the end of this tutorial.

```
make -j4
```

I get this error:

```
`15%] Building CXX object        3rdparty/carotene/hal/carotene/CMakeFiles/carotene_objs.dir/src/absdiff.cpp.o
c++: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘--param=ipcp-unit-growth=100000’; did you mean ‘--param=ipa-cp-unit-growth=’?
make[2]: *** [3rdparty/carotene/hal/carotene/CMakeFiles/carotene_objs.dir/build.make:82: 3rdparty/carotene/hal/carotene/CMakeFiles/carotene_objs.dir/src/absdiff.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2034: 3rdparty/carotene/hal/carotene/CMakeFiles/carotene_objs.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 15%] Built target IlmImf
[ 15%] Built target libwebp
[ 15%] Built target libprotobuf
make: *** [Makefile:182: all] Error 2 `
```

I tried

```
sed -i 's/--param=ipcp-unit-growth=100000/--param=ipa-cp-unit-growth=/g' CMakeCache.txt
```

but it didnt work.

I also tried

```
find . -type f -name "CMakeFiles*" -exec grep -l --null '--param=ipcp-unit-growth=100000' {} + | xargs -0 sed -i 's/--param=ipcp-unit-growth=100000/--param=ipa-cp-unit-growth=/g'
```

The objective of these commands was to try and replace the unrecognized command line with what it was suggesting as a replacement. I am still getting an error.

Comment: OpenCV comes with compiler. Here is link: https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: The link you posted was 5 year old.